# For ionic-angular hybrid app in Windows10 Device(950XL) after latest update(version -10.0.14393.189), selectbox crashing the app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, windows-10-mobile, ngcordova

I am creating an Ionic with Angular based hybrid app for Android, iOS & Windows.The app has a functionality select dropdown which was working fine in all three platforms. Once my Windows10 device(950XL) updated to latest version -10.0.14393.189, its crashing the app on tapping on the select box. When I had the old version-10.0.14393.67, the app was working fine. I tested few cordova apps in the same device has the same issue on tapping on dropdown. Kindly help me out to sort this issue.

Comment: Could you maybe post some codes or share a basic demo that can reproduce your problem?

Comment: <select ng-model="output.departmentId" id="depart_label" data-tap-disabled="true" >
                <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled" translate="SelectText">Please select</option>
                <option>Department 2</option>
                <option>Department 3</option>
                <option>Department 4</option>
                <option>Department 5</option>
                <option>Department 6</option>
            </select>

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the WebView control in applications built using the Windows Phone (Universal) target platform and then deployed to a device running Windows 10 Phone. I suggest as a workaround you set Windows target version to 10.0 (in config.xml) and build for Windows-AnyCPU platform. This should run correctly on a Windows 10 phone.

To continue to support Windows 8.1 phone you will need maintain a separate package with Windows Phone (Universal) platform target and Windows 8.1 as target version.